# 'require' work but 'require_once' doesn't work

Tags: php

When I use `require_once` or `include_once` to include a file it does not work, while when I use `require` or `include` it works fine.

```
public function ParseURL() {
    require_once (APP_PATH . "config/config.php");

    $this->url_as_parts = explode('/', $this->url);
    $class = isset($this->url_as_parts[0]) ? $this->url_as_parts[0] : $config['default_controller'];
    $method = isset($this->url_as_parts[1]) ? $this->url_as_parts[1] : "index";
    $parms = isset($this->url_as_parts[2]) ? $this->url_as_parts[2] : "";

    if (!class_exists($class)) {
        trigger_error("The class {$class} not exists <br/>");
        exit;
    }
    $controller = Object::get($class);
    if (!method_exists($controller, $method)) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        include(SYSTEM_PATH . "languages/" . $config['system_language'] . "/errors/404_not_found.html");
        exit;           
    }

    if (empty($parms)) {
        $controller->{$method}();
    } else {
        $parms_array = array_slice($this->url_as_parts, 2);
        call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $parms_array);
    }
}
```

The following line does not produce an error and the path is correct
`require_once (APP_PATH . "config/config.php");` but I cant access `$config['system_language']` which is inside the file `config.php`.

Note that when I change the `require_once` to `require` or `include`, everything is OK.

Comment: Because you use function twice and for all times after first one this file doesn't included?

Comment: Baybe you included it once, and overwrite the values of `$config` somewhere else later in your code

Comment: Oh, It's inside a function... Do `global $config;` inside the function or pass `$config` as parameter to the function

Comment: I have changed the idea which get the configuration data. Any way I thank each person helped me.

Answer (score 1):

As comes from `require_once` description - file required only **once**

Any other `require_once` of this file **will not** work.

And you obviously run you function `ParseURL` more than once. So, your `require_once` not working on second and consecutive calls.

So, you can use just `require` or, as I see this is part of a class, create, for example, a wrapper method which will assign `config` data to your class variable. I.e:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $this->config = require_once('FILE');
}
```

In this case your config file should **return** array or object of config variables.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that something else includes `config/config.php`, and then redefines/overwrites the variable `$config`?

The difference between `require_once()` and is regular counterparts (`include()` etc) is that `require_once()` only includes (and executes, if applicable) something if it hasn't been included before.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are already loading config/config.php somewhere before in your code.
Calling `require_once(APP_PATH . "config/config.php");` checks that the file config.php already is included and hence does not include it inside that function.
That is the reason your function does not have access to `$config` variable.

Hope that helps.